# Replace values from second row onwards in a pandas pipe method

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am wondering how to replace values from second row onwards in a pipe method (connecting to the rest of steps).

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Date": ["2020-01-01", "2021-01-01", "2022-01-01"],
        "Pop": [90, 70, 60],
    }
)

         Date  Pop
0  2020-01-01   90
1  2021-01-01   70
2  2022-01-01   60
```

Current solution

```
df.iloc[1:] = np.nan
```

Expected output

```
         Date  Pop
0  2020-01-01   90
1  2021-01-01  NaN
2  2022-01-01  NaN
```

Comment: what's wrong with your logic/code right now? seems its giving what you want

Comment: @eshirvana I want to bring it into a chain format.

Comment: I'm almost sure it is not possible to write this as a pure chain method, as you'd need a df shape, or index, or both

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use `assign` like this:

```
df.assign(Pop=df.loc[[0], 'Pop'])
```

Output:

```
         Date   Pop
0  2020-01-01  90.0
1  2021-01-01   NaN
2  2022-01-01   NaN
```

Note: `assign` works with *nice* column headers, if your headers have spaces or special characters you will need to use a different method.